# How does list assignment work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, list, parameters, variadic-functions

I'm reading [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) Exercises section and I've encountered problem with the following code in the book:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

First of all, I do not understand how it `console.log` can have that output. I am especially confused with the `list = {value: array[i], rest: list};` part. I do know that in the first iteration, `array[i]` is equal to `20`, therefore the list is now `{value: 20, rest: null}`. In the second iteration, `array[i]` is `10`, therefore the list is now `{value: 10, rest: list}` and `list` refers to `{value: 20, rest: null}`, therefore we have `list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}`. Is my understanding correct? If it is, I find it very confusing how `list`, while being assigned, can still remember the value it contained previously, i.e. `{value: 20, rest: null}`. Could someone please explain this?

Second, I do not understand why it mentions that:

> 'Building up a list is easier when done back to front. So arrayToList
>   could iterate over the array backwards (see the previous exercise)
>   and, for each element, add an object to the list. You can use a local
>   binding to hold the part of the list that was built so far and use an
>   assignment like list = {value: X, rest: list} to add an element.'

Why is it easier to build up a list when done back to front? Is it possible, though, to build a list when done front to back?

Third, when I tried to change the above code to the following:

```
function arrayToList(...array) { //Only change is from array to ...array
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: [10, 20], rest: null} Why did the output change?
```

Comment: The right-hand side of an assignment expression is **fully evaluated** before the assignment is made. Before the `=` operator does its thing, the value is completely determined. Therefore, the starting value of `list` is perfectly intact while that object is being constructed.

Comment: @Pointy I see, I've never known that as the book did not mention it. Does that fact hold true for other languages such as C and Python, too? Furthermore, I'm still not so clear about the difference between an expression and a statement, could you provide me a comprehensive yet concise link to it or explain briefly to me?

Comment: Generally yes, though it's generally a good idea to be very hesitant in assuming that a new language you're learning works like a language you already know, even when syntax looks similar.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer—if it didn't behave that way, you'd have an endless loop where the value of *list* keeps updating itself. So the RHS must be fully evaluated before making the assignment. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use spread syntax in your second version, you're saying that you want all the arguments to the function to be collected into an array (called "array").  When you actually *call* the function, you pass a *single* argument: the array `[10, 20]`. Thus, in the function, `array` will be `[[10, 20]]` — an array with that array as its single element. The loop, therefore, will only go through one iteration.

If you were to call that second version function with

```
console.log(arrayToList(10, 20))
```

you'd get a result much more like what you get in your first sample of code. The "array" parameter in the function would be an array of *two* values, `10` and `20`.

As to the question about what an "expression" is, that's a syntactic construct that is kind-of easy to "get" intuitively but (especially in JavaScript) pretty complicated in fine detail. Basically something like a mathematical (algebraic) construction, or a comparison, or even a single variable reference or a function call, is an expression. A *statement* can consist of nothing more than a single (possibly big) expression, but a statement can also be a `for` loop, a `var` or `let` declaration, a `return` statement, and various other things. JavaScript syntax generally introduces statements with particular keywords, *except* for expression statements.

Comment: I see, I understand what it meant now. However, I'm not confused with the following code: `let numbers = [5, 1, 7];` and `console.log(Math.max(...numbers))` which means `console.log(Math.max([5, 1, 7]`, right? It outputted `7`, but how do you know the `max` of an array when you're not even accessing the array?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer no, `Math.max(... numbers)` means `Math.max(5, 1, 7)`. The whole point of the spread syntax in a function call is to expand (or "spread") an array into an argument list; otherwise, you'd just pass the array directly.